# "Punctured stalk" of a locally ringed space (at a closed point) is the fraction field of the stalk?

Tags: sheaf-theory, ringed-spaces

Let $(X,\mathcal{O})$ be a locally ringed space. For $x \in X$ a closed point (i.e. $\{x\}$ is closed in $X$), let $\mathcal{O}_x$ denote the stalk of $\mathcal{O}$ at $x$; and define the "punctured stalk" $\mathcal{P}_x$ of $\mathcal{O}$ at $x$ as the directed colimit (in commutative rings)
of $\mathcal{O}(V\setminus\{x\})$ where $V$ ranges over all open neighborhoods of $x$ in $X$.

My question is, if $\mathcal{O}_x$ is an integral domain, do we have $\mathcal{P}_x = \mathrm{Frac}(\mathcal{O}_x)$, the fraction field of $\mathcal{O}_x$?

More generally, if $\mathcal{O}_x$ is not an integral domain,
then is $\mathcal{P}_x$ the localization of $\mathcal{O}_x$
obtained by inverting all nonzero elements of its unique maximal ideal (which also consists of all its non-units)?

Edit: added the requirement that $x$ must be a closed point. (Thank you to the comments for pointing out this necessity.)

Comment: I think you should add the assumption that $X$ is a $T_1$ space, so that $V \setminus \{x\}$ is open. Or, alternatively, define $\mathcal{O}(V \setminus \{x\})$ in the case that $\{x\}$ is not closed. Or, for another alternative, add the assumption that $\{x\}$ is closed in $X$.

Comment: For the definition to make sense we need $x$ to be a closed point. There doesn't seem to be any relation between $\mathcal{P}_x$ and the localization of $\mathcal{O}_x$ (for it to be an equality it would pass through some map $\mathcal{O}_x\to \mathcal{P}_x$. Consider a constant sheaf of local rings on $X = \{0, 1\}$. With discrete topology, the punctured stalk is zero and with topology consisting of $\{\emptyset, \{1\}, X\}$ the punctured stalk at $0$ is the same local ring.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk Oh right, yes $\{x\}$ must be closed for this to make sense (or we need to pick some definition when $\{x\}$ is not closed); thank you for pointing out this issue. I'll edit my question appropriately

Comment: @redwhisker Sorry right, $\{x\}$ needs to be a closed point for this to make sense as is. However, supposing $\{x\}$ is closed, then wouldn't the maps $\mathcal{O}(V) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(V\setminus \{x\}) \rightarrow \mathcal{P}_x$ provide a coherent "co-cone" out of $(F(V))_{V \ni x}$ into $\mathcal{P}_x$, giving a morphism $\mathcal{O}_x \rightarrow \mathcal{P}_x$?

Comment: @IndraneelTambe yes, you're right, for some reason I was thinking of maps going the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $X = \{x\}$ be a one-point space, with sheaf $\mathcal{O}$ defined by $\mathcal{O}(X) = \mathbb{C}$.

Then $\mathcal{O}_x = \mathbb{C}$, but $\mathcal{P}_x = \mathcal{O}(\varnothing) = 0$ is not the fraction field of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: This example hadn't occurred to me, thank you!